# How to convert json array to json object in lambda python function

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to convert json array to json object in lambda python function, Below is my lambda code:

```
import sys
import logging
import pymysql
import json
rds_host=".com"
name="name"
password="pass"
db_name="DB"
port = 3306
def save_events(event):
result = []
conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, 
connect_timeout=30)
with conn.cursor() as cur:
  cur.execute("select * from bodyPart")
for row in cur:
  result.append(list(row))
print ("Data from RDS...")
print (result)
cur.close()
bodyparts = json.dumps(result)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  save_events(event)
  return bodyparts
```

Below is the output
Response:

```
[[1, \"Chest\", \"link"], [2, \"Shoulder\", 
null], [3, \"Arms\", null]]
```

How to get a response like

```
 {id='1',
 name='chest',
 link='......', ....}
```

Comment: Apply the data from the row to a dict instead of just doing `list(row)`.

Comment: Use `with conn.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cur`. Then `cur.fetchall()` wil return a list of dicts, with the column names as keys.

Comment: @ekhumoro I used the above connector instead of a normal connector, an empty json object is getting returned

Comment: Well, you probably need to do `result = cur.fetchall()`, and get rid of the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment your function `save_events` is not mentioning the event passed in. But the immediate problem you asked about is solved with code like this:

```py
result = []

conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host,
        user=name,
        passwd=password,
        db=db_name,
        connect_timeout=30)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM bodyPart")

data = cursor.fetchall()
#data = [[1, "Chest", "link"], [2, "Shoulder", None], [3, "Arms", None]]

element = {}
for row in data:
    element["ident"], element["name"], element["link"] = row
    result.append(element)

print("Data from RDS...")
print json.dumps(result)
conn.close()
```

As mentioned in a comment, your rows are dicts not lists.